# What data can be accessed through the $_SESSION superglobal

Tags: php, session, superglobals

I had this question in a quiz:
Once a session is started, all data related to the session is accessible through the $_SESSION superglobal.
A. True
B. False

My answer was false, because I thought only the data stored explicitly like this: $_SESSION["something"] = "something", is accessible.
But I the correct answer was true.

So, what else can I get from this superglobal? Or maybe it's just the wording issues, the actual question was asking everything in this session stored like this can be accessible?

Comment: I guess it depends on how you see it. If they refer to all data the user stores in the session, then yes, it will be accessible through the `$_SESSION`-variable. That's what it's for. But if you see the session id as "data related to the session", then the answer is no, since you can't get that value from the `$_SESSION`-variable.

Answer (score 1):

$_SESSION superglobal may be to use only with session. When you pass data with session also, you can get data with it. Data types can be string, int,float,array etc.

For example:

```php
<?php
    // Start new or resume existing session.
    session_start();
    
    // Add values to the session.
    $_SESSION['item_name'] = 'value'; // string
    $_SESSION['item_name'] = 0; // int
    $_SESSION['item_name'] = 0.0; // float

    // Get session values.
    $value = $_SESSION['item_name'];
```